# Can't get Excel drop-down list (combobox) value with python

Tags: python, excel, combobox, drop-down-menu, xlrd

I have an excel file with a drop-down list and I would like to access its current value from python.

In vba the code is really simple :

```
Sheets("name_of_my_sheet").name_of_my_list.value
```

I looked for an equivalent in xlrd but couldn't find one.

Comment: looks like the code you posted looks at a list instead of at the drop down box that uses the stated list for it's contents.

Comment: So how do I access this list ?

Comment: Just go to the cell that the list is on and read the contents of it.

Comment: It was the first thing I tried :) 
And I get an empty cell when I try to get it.
The only way I can find right now is to have a vba on change that actually put its value in a cell and read it from that cell but it's not really elegant.

Comment: I think I got it. This "not elegant" way is the only one since this list only exists when you launch the spreadsheet program that executes the vba, it can't be read from the xls file directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my answer. The list the drop-down box is created at run time in vba so you can't "read" its value from the xls.

The solution is to write in VBA an on change method that will actually write the value to the cell under the box.

```
Sub My_List_Change()
   Sheets("Containing your box").Cells(x,y) = My_List.value // x,y being the coordinates of the cell hidden by the box
```

Then each time you save your sheet and want to read it from python you can access the current value.